# 18.04: Lenovo Ideapad 320 - Touchpad failed

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

My touch pad was working when I first installed Ubuntu 18.04. I found similar problems with answers suggesting to update the kernel. Now those answers are old.

These are my system's properties:

```
Linux abolfazl 4.15.0-72-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 26 12:20:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

 xinput list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  
⎜   ↳ USB OPTICAL MOUSE                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3336-001                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (
    ↳ EasyCamera: EasyCamera                    id=10   [slave  keyboard (
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (

cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Probably some updates caused the problem, but do you have any idea how to find a solution?

Comment: Make a different Ubuntu version LiveUSB for testing. Get an ISO file for a 'flavour' of 19.10 with a different Desktop (not the standard Ubuntu GNOME). Download @  https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours .The ISO used to make a LiveUSB should be checked for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 . Make it following Canonical,(Ubuntu's publishers)  instructions on your PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 .Once you make the LiveUSB, boot from it, and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: This is a well known bug with this kernel and Synaptics touchpad. There are lots of similar questions. A workaround is to boot with a previous kernel and wait for the next with a fix.

Comment: Yep. https://askubuntu.com/search?q=ideapad+320+touchpad confirms it.